# App.Config file in console application C#

Tags: c#, console

I have a console application in which I want to write the name of a file.

```
Process.Start("blah.bat");
```

Normally, I would have something like that in windows application by writing the name of the file `'blah.bat'` to **Settings** file in **Properties**.
However, here I didn't find any *Settings* file and I added an **app.config** for the same purpose.

I am not sure what to write here in **app.config**, that would lead to me to achieve similar thing as in ***Windows Forms***.

For eg: In windows forms. `Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.BatchFile);`
where `BatchFile` is a string in settings file in Properties.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

You can add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your project and then:

`using System.Configuration;`

then

`string sValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchFile"];`

with an `app.config` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="BatchFile" value="blah.bat" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["blah.bat"]` is available but gives a warning that this is obsolete. Whenn I try to use `ConfigurationManager` as above, I get an error saying ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context. :-/

Comment: Make sure that you also add a reference to System.Configuration - the `using` durective only works when you have a reference to the assembly you're trying to use.

Comment: late comment but for me my mistake was that I forgot upper-casing 'S' from appSettings

Comment: how do I get an int or bool, Ie not a string?

Comment: @Zapnologica Everything is a string, as far as `AppSettings` is considered. If you have settings strings that contain numbers, you'll have to parse them by calling `int.TryParse()` or the like. The same goes for any other value that you want to treat something other than a string.

Answer (score 51):

For .NET Core, add System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from NuGet manager.

And read **appSetting** from **App.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="appSetting1" value="1000" />
</appSettings>
```

Add System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from NuGet Manager

[image]

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("appSetting1")
```

Answer (score 9):

use this

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Keyname")
```

Comment: you can save your configuration on appsettion and for Fetch the value use      example .

Comment: Provides support for runtime version 1.x. This is [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Configuration_ConfigurationSettings_AppSettings) now. Please use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`

Comment: System.Configuration assembly is needed in references.