# Error while getting the config file parameters in C# console application

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, config, azure-keyvault

I am following this page to encrypt the blob using azure key vault using C#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support&tabs=dotnet11#use-key-vault-secrets

But getting an error in this code block

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("accountName"),
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("accountKey")
            );
```

> **Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException**: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Marshaling to and from COM interface pointers isn't supported).

*app.config*

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="accountName" value="myaccount"/>
    <add key="accountKey" value="theaccountkey"/>
    <add key="clientId" value="theclientid"/>
    <add key="clientSecret" value="theclientsecret"/>
    <add key="container" value="stuff"/>
</appSettings>
```

I tried the solutions given in link below, but those didn't work either

[System.argumentnullexception is null using microsoft azure storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658416/system-argumentnullexception-is-null-using-microsoft-azure-storage)

Comment: @TheGeneral - I was using that code because it was provided in the official Microsoft azure page- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support&tabs=dotnet11#use-key-vault-secrets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my system .Not facing the error that you are getting .I passed the credentials directly instead of reading them from `app.config`.I think issue with reading credentials from `app.config` **Pass the credentials directly**.

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(("name"),("key"));
I tried the to pass but that didnt work either, it showing same error at same stage

Comment: I have this warning message while I run the project

`warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.ConfigurationManager 4.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`

Comment: which version of  .net framework you are using?

Comment: using .NET 5.0 for this example

Comment: Check the  with `Microsoft.Azure.ConfigurationManager  `, In application where you using this package ,I think you used it to read the Credentials from `app.config`.Please remove that package and try it again and let me know still facing issue.

Comment: Started working thank you